# Configure DotTrace profiling VSTest on TeamCity

Tags: c#, teamcity, performance-testing, vstest, dottrace

[DotTrace can be used to profile tests on TeamCity](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/08/27/performance-profiling-in-continuous-integration-dottrace-and-teamcity/#comment-446078). But this example works with NUnit, while my tests are written in Visual Studio Tests. When running my tests I use the build-in test engine VSTest, no such option is available for the DotTrace profiler plugin. Instead I need to specify the path for the test engine executable.

I did find an executable VSTest.exe but it's path includes "Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs", so unsurprisingly it doesn't work. Saying it can't find a start.bat file, that does indeed not exist in that .exe file.

What is the executable path that TeamCity uses for VSTest?

Then I can configure the performance test to use that test engine. I know the tests can be executed using DotTrace, having run it in Visual Studio, just don't want to install Visual Studio and the DotTrace plugin there when there's a TeamCity plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3b87ef2e-41ee-4597-bf25-985f7917a483/how-can-i-run-vstestconsoleexe-without-vs-installed?forum=vstest), you can install Visual Studio Test Agent on your TeamCity Agent and then specify *vstest.console.exe* as a profiling target in the XML config. 
Nevertheless, I suggest you to try a [new dotTrace plugin version](http://teamcity.jetbrains.com/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/buildType:TeamCityPluginsByJetBrains_DotTrace_Build,pinned:true,status:SUCCESS,branch:master/artifacts/content/dotTrace.zip) (if it asks you for credentials, specify *guest* with no password). It's not yet officially announced but fully functional. 
The main difference is that the plugin is now integrated into 'unit testing' build steps, e.g. Visual Stiduo Tests, NUnit, MSpec, MSTest. *So, it doesn't require a configuration file.* Thus, after you install the plugin, all unit testing steps will get the additional option **Run build step under dotTrace profiler**. All you need to do is add the Visual Studio Tests step, check this option there and specify performance thresholds as usual.